# OpenSSLCrypto: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_OSSL_PROVIDER_load"

Tags: openssl, azerothcore

I got this error running cmake and make installing [azerothcore](https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk).

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OSSL_PROVIDER_load", referenced from:
      OpenSSLCrypto::threadsSetup() in libcommon.a(OpenSSLCrypto.cpp.o)
  "_OSSL_PROVIDER_set_default_search_path", referenced from:
      OpenSSLCrypto::threadsCleanup() in libcommon.a(OpenSSLCrypto.cpp.o)
  "_OSSL_PROVIDER_unload", referenced from:
      OpenSSLCrypto::threadsCleanup() in libcommon.a(OpenSSLCrypto.cpp.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved it with the following steps:

- remove all the references about openssl from `.bash_profile`
- uninstall all the openssl versions
- install openssl@3 using `brew install openssl@3`
- run cmake again